# Symfony2 route not found order

Tags: symfony

I built a symfony2 project and I have a problem with my app/config/routing.yml.  I have two routes for two bundles and only the last route can be resolved.  If I change the order, still only last route can be resolved and for the first route I have an error message "No route found for "GET /collaborateur/".  Any solutions?

This is my app/config/routing.yml:

```
front_office:
    resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /collaborateur

back_office:
    resource: "@BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /platform
```

Comment: Post here your `"@FrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"` and `"@BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"` configs

Answer (score 2):

First, it would be good to run `router:debug` in order to see which routes got loaded in fact.

```
php app/console router:debug
```

You should be able to see both of those here.

Secondly, I noticed that you sent a request to `GET /collaborateur/`. You might be hitting a known `Symfony2` routing problem when it comes to trailing slash. It was described in this **[cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html)**.

Can you try to open `/collaborateur` (without trailing slash)?

Comment: the route work if i change the order of the two routes like this :                              ------------------------------------------------------------                                                            back_office:

    resource: "@BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /platform
front_office:

    resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /collaborateur

Comment: Yes, I got that. But if you have disjunctive prefixes for both `.yml`, the order should really make no difference...